# how to convert depth in Z-cordinate

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate, kinect-sdk

I'm making a project in which i need to draw user's feet in a rectangle of 640*480
and i'm mapping the skeleton joints coordinate into depth coordinates to fit it in the box,

but the DepthImagePoint gives x-y coordinate and depth(in mm) but i want x-z coordinate.
How can I get the z coordinate to fit in the resolution of 640*480?

or Can i somehow convert skeleton joints coordinate to proper resolution to fit the box?

I'm using Microsoft Kinect SDK with C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions in the `CoordinateMapper` that will map points between the different data streams.  `MapSkeletonPontToDepthPoint` being the first to come to mind.  Others in the mapper may also assist in finding the proper depth mapping you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj883690.aspx

Comment: thank you for replying....!! i have tried this method it coverts the x-y-z coordinate of skeleton joints into depth X-Y coordinate and a depth value but the depth value is in mm. but i want the depth value as z coordinate in proportion of X-Y actually i only need X and Z. any suggestions to convert the depth into z coordinate.

Comment: Depth is expressed in millimeters and the Skeleton is expressed in meters.  I do not believe these functions alter those units.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx